# SystemJS: how to add file extensions for interal dependencies?

Tags: angular, systemjs

There is Angular 2 app, using typescript for coding and SystemJS for module loading.

```
//sydtemjs.config.js
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        map: {
        'normalizr': 'node_modules/normalizr/dist/src/index.js' //mapping normalizr library
        },
         packages: {
             normalizr: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
         }
```

index.js is loaded successfully, but it contains dependencies:

```
//node_modules/normalizr/dist/src/index.js
var _Entity = require('./schemas/Entity');
var _Array = require('./schemas/Array');
//etc
```

Browser makes a request to base_path/node_modules/normalizr/dist/src/schemas/Array (without js extension) and server returns 404.

How to config systemjs to attach js extension for internal modules? Why  doesn't defaultExtension solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove `packages` part and instead use `defaultJSExtensions` globally?

Something like this:

```
{
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  map: {
    'normalizr': 'node_modules/normalizr/dist/src/index
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid a solution which uses defaultJSExtensions as this property has been deprecated in newer versions of systemjs.

You will need to map all dependencies of normalizer too for this to work, otherwise, systemjs will have no concept of knowing how to load.

You might be better off using jspm to automatically create the config in this scenario.

Comment: It worth mentioning that current latest main version of jspm (0.16.53) will generate config.js that uses defaultJSExtensions:)